# .prototype and [[prototype]]. Why is .prototype an empty object?

Tags: javascript, prototype, prototype-programming

I am actually very confused with prototypes right now despite reading most articles on StackOverflow.

```js
function Foo() {

}

Foo.prototype.speak = function() {
    console.log('Foo');
};

function Bar() {

}

console.log(Bar.prototype); // {}

Bar.prototype = Object.create(Foo.prototype);

console.log(Bar.prototype); // {} ----- (1)

Bar.prototype.speak = function() {  // ----------(2)
    console.log('Bar');
};   

console.log(Bar.prototype); // { speak: [Function] }  ----- (3)
```

Question:

1) Why is **(1)** an empty object after `Object.create`. Shouldn't it turn an object with a `speak method` from `Foo` ?

2) What am I actually changing on **(2)** ?? The `Bar` object or the `prototype` object ? What is actually happening?

3) What's happening on **(3)**.

4) How is [[prototype]] involved in all of this? What I do know is [[prototype]] is used for look ups if the current object does not contain a property.

Just to be sure, `.prototype !== [[prototype]]` but `[[prototype]] === __proto__` ?

**Sorry if this is a duplicate. Because I can't seem to answer those questions despite multiple similar questions.**

Comment: Object.create doesn't copy an object, it creates one with the prototype set to the object you pass in. If you try call `(new Bar()).speak();` after (1) it will work (and output "Foo") Your prototype chain is one object removed from where you think it is. Try `console.log(Bar.prototype.prototype)`

Comment: Another way of explaining what you see is that console.log does only output the `ownProperties` of the object, not all properties/method that could be found along the prototype chain. Write your own logging function if you want all the chain displayed.

Answer (score -1):

You can't change the prototype of a function/object by simply trying to assign it. You need to set it at the time of object creation or you should use ES6 features to change it.

So, `Bar.prototype = Object.create(Foo.prototype);` doesn't make any sense.

`[[prototype]]` is the internal representation of the real prototype of an object.

Probably you should re-arrange your test case based on these fundamentals and seek explanation.